# Azure website. How to find logs about stopping service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

is there a way to find when was azure website stopped? (I'm stopped website through portal but I can't remember when..)

I was looking for some logs, but I didn't find anything useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing you have is **Management Services** on the azure portal, there you can go to **Operation Logs** and see actions that were done to your web site, only problem is there is no specific **Site Stopped** reference, you can look for **UpdateWebSite** which can either be start or stopped the site.